# Efficient method for writing to empty pandas dataframe or panel without looping through indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, apply

I was wondering if there was a preferred method for writing values to either a panel or dataframe object without using .loc[index] to assign row by row.

Here's an example (setting up the empty Panel):

```
items = ['item1','item2','item3']
major_axis = np.arange(10)
minor_axis = ['A','B','C','D']

data = np.ndarray(shape=(3,10,4), dtype='d')
data[:] = np.NaN
```

Panel creation:

```
    myPanel=pd.Panel(data=data,items=items, major_axis=major_axis, minor_axis= minor_axis)
```

Suppose I wanted to write an array to each row of the resulting dataframe when iterating over the panel's items. In loop form it seems really goofy and not very efficient.

```
for item in myPanel.items:
    for idx in myPanel[item].index:
        myPanel[item].loc[idx] = np.array([4,3,2,1])
```

I've been trying to use dataframe.apply() and panel.apply() with lambda in order to do this in a nicer way, but am having trouble actually writing the values using the apply method.

Here's my feeble attempt at a solution:

define a function that would write to each row of a dataframe:

```
def f(x): return np.array([4,3,2,1])
```

Then do something like this, but in a manner that actually works?

```
myPanel.apply(lambda x: x.apply(f(x.loc[x.index])), axis = [0,1])
```

I'm sure this is probably bad form even if it did work.

The idea was that the innermost apply would operate over each row of the dataframe that results from the outermost apply()'s operation.

Is this a silly endeavor? Is apply() still behaving like a loop, but designed for operations that reference the values already stored in the dataframe/panel-like object, and not to be used for setting values?

UPDATE:
I didn't do a very good job of specifying my objectives here, so I'll try elaborate more. I also think I combined several questions into one large obscure one.

My primary objective was to determine the best (most efficient) method to write to individual values in a Panel. The code I am working on references an empty Panel (filled with NaN's) that I created during initialization, and then proceeds to overwrite these values at some later point with actual numerical data.

I wasn't entirely sure how I wanted to design the methods to write data to the empty Panel. I was curious about using the apply() method as opposed to manually selecting on a dimension of the Panel in a loop, since it seems apply() kind of automatically iterates over an axis and allows one to perform some kind of transform over this axis simultaneously.

To achieve this end, I was considering designing a function that would handle the "work" being done to write to individual rows of a dataframe either by using df.apply(write_row_function)) or just iterating over the dataframe's index and saying df.loc[i] = write_row_function().

For the containing Panel, I was considering using apply again in the fashion: panel.apply(write_dataframe_to_panel_function, axis = 0(?)) or iterating via:

```
for i in Panel.items:
     Panel[i] = write_dataframe_to_panel_function()
```

My issue with apply() involved not being sure how to use it to update itself at that location in the apply() method with data from a function in one shot.

At the end of the day, I began to question the usefulness of trying to use apply() when it seems to behave as a loop and does not seem to be particularly easy to use as a method to write new new data to the axis apply() is stepping through.

If there was no performance advantage to using apply() in such a manner or if I was overlooking a major functionality, I was hoping for insights from the community that might steer me in a more productive direction.

I hope this is a little clearer than my original attempt. If not, I'll keep trying :)

Comment: In your attempt, you use `x.loc` but you specifically ask for something that doesn't use `.loc`.  Are you ok using `loc` or not?

Comment: Also, what you've asked is very vague.  Your question is far more likely to be answered if you show a clear example of what you are looking for.  See this link for more guidance.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Agree with piRSquared. As to the questions about apply, it is indeed a `for` loop (though one implemented in cython). Looking at the pandas github, you can work from frame.py -> apply() -> lib.reduce() -> lib's #include "reduce.pyx" -> to [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/reduce.pyx) to see that *ultimately,* it is a `for` loop.

Comment: appreciate the feedback, i'll edit and try to be more specific.

Comment: @BrandonJ: "The code I am working on references an empty Panel (filled with NaN's) that I created during initialization, and then proceeds to overwrite these values at some later point with actual numerical data." Is there a reason you aren't initializing the panel with this numerical data?

Comment: @StarFox: Sorry it took me so long to repond, but yes. The numerical data hasn't "arrived" yet. Assume it's time series data and all I know is what the index timestamps will be, but not their associated values.